# Meteor cordova build

Tags: cordova, meteor, plugins, build

I'm building a meteor cordova app for iOS and Android, too. All works like a sharm, but every time i run "meteor run ios-device" meteor re-download all the plugins spending a consistent amount of time. I'm searching a way to avoid this situation. There is a way for download plugin only the first time i compile my app?. I just try to remove and re add platforms, but nothing change. In my .meteor folder i have a file with the list of plugin, but i cannoty find a folder with the plugin data.